# Add point data to mesh and save as vtu

Tags: python, pyvista

I am trying to add more properties to a *vtu file using `pyvista`. I have written a python code which generates 9 columns of data for all the points in the mesh. I want to add them to the existing *vtu file. I found `add_field_data`, but I want to add as point data, not field data or cell data.

I also considered converting the point data in the original *vtu file to a numpy array and concatenating them, but I do not know how to save this numpy array as a *vtu file.

Any help in any of the 2 directions is highly appreciated, although I would prefer the former.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me why we have `add_field_data()` and no `add_point_data()` or `add_cell_data()`, but you can always use the `point_data`/`cell_data`/`field_data` attributes of mesh types, see for instance [this tutorial page](https://tutorial.pyvista.org/tutorial/02_mesh/index.html#what-are-attributes).

If you already have a mesh and a 1d array of scalars `scalars` of shape `(mesh.n_points,)` (or a 2d array with shape `(mesh.n_points, d)`, actually) then all you need to do with your mesh is

```py
mesh.point_data['name of your point data comes here'] = scalars
```

You'll get an error in case the shape of `scalars` is invalid. You can then just

1. read the `.vtu` file with something like `mesh = pv.read('name_of_your_file.vtu')`
2. add the scalars as above
3. call `mesh.plot()` or something more complicated to make sure the scalars look the way you expect them to (optional but recommended)
4. call `mesh.save('output_file_name.vtu')`

If you plot your mesh with your 9-component scalars of shape `(n_points, 9)` you'll probably want to choose a single component (a single column) to plot by. You can do this with

```py
mesh.plot(scalars='name of your point data comes here', component=3)
```

to pick out column index 3.